# Debian kernel package update freezes

Tags: debian, apt

So I have a Debian squeeze i386 install, and I'm trying to update to 3.2. I added the sources to the backports, I updated apt-get, I installed the `firmware-linux-free`, and when I try to install the image it freezes. It prompts me to say yes, and seems to finish, but rather than returning to the console, it just displays this screen that says:

```
* Some HP Smart Array controllers are now handled by the new 'hpsa' driver, rather than the 'cciss' driver.

...

blah blah blah some boring stuff

...

-- Ben Hutchings <ben@decadent.org.uk> Wed, 16 Mar 2011 13:19:34 +0000

(END)
```

I read somewhere that this happens if you don't have the non-free firmware, which I installed. It still doesn't work. The computer is an HP(which is apparently the type of computers that have these problems).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Maybe it's something entirely different, I've never updated the kernel before.

Comment: Try hitting `q`.  I think what you see is the pager displaying a possible important changelog.

Comment: You are correct. I can't believe it was something so incredibly simple, I spent hours trying to figure this out last night.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `apt-listchanges` package installed, important news about new packages is shown before they are installed.  The news is shown with your "pager", which just displays the text one screen at a time.  The method to exit the pager depends on which pager it found, but as sr_ said, <kbd>q</kbd> should work.

Comment: That was it, I can't believe I spent so much time trying to figure out something so simple. I hit 'q' and things progressed flawlessly.